# How do I implement a brushfire algorithm in Lua?

Tags: algorithm, lua, adjacency-list, breadth-first-search

I am working on implementing "Goal-based vector field pathfinding" (demonstrated in the article at [this link](http://gamedevelopment.tutsplus.com/tutorials/understanding-goal-based-vector-field-pathfinding--gamedev-9007))  It requires that I label every node in my world graph with a path distance from the goal node and recommends using a brushfire (wavefront) algorithm to do this.  This is the area I am having issues in.  When I get to the 8th iteration of my while loop and the 6th iteration of my nested `for`, I get a nil reference error on the marked line.

**g** is my graph, which has an 8-way adjacency list form.

**q** is an instance of [this](http://www.lua.org/pil/11.4.html) FIFO lua library.

**rtx** and **rty** are the x and y coords of the root node.

**d** is an iterator added to keep track of the path distance assigned to each node.

The structure of each node in the graph is not the same as the structure of a node being processed.

Node for processing:

```
n = {}
n[1] = x coord
n[2] = y coord
n[3] = adjacency list (eight entries)
n.vX = x componant of vector for vector field
n.vY = y componant of vector for vector field
```

Node stored in graph:

```
n = {}
n[1] = adjacency list
n.vX = x componant of vector for vector field
n.vY = y componant of vector for vector field
```

Beneath is my implementation so far.  The t in the for loop is just a temporary node used to pass information along to the queue.  BTW t is where the distance of all the nodes gets set.

```
local function brushFire( g, rtx, rty )
    local q = q.new()
    local s = {}
    s[1] = rtx
    s[2] = rty
    s[3] = g[rtx][rty][3]
    s.dist = 0
    q:pushRight( s )
    s = nil
    local d = 0

    while( table.getn( q.list[q.first] ) ~= 0 ) do
        print( d )
        local n = q:popLeft()
        setDist( g, n )
        print( #n[3] )
        for i = 1, #n[3] do
            print( ":"..i )
            if( g[n[3][i][4]][n[3][i][2]].v ~= true ) then
                g[n[3][i][5]][n[3][i][2]].v = true
                local t = {}
                t[1] = n[3][i][1]
                t[2] = n[3][i][2]
                t[3] = g[n[3][i][7]][n[3][i][2]][1]  <------Error here
                t.dist = d
                q:pushRight( t )
                t = nil
            end
        end
        d = d + 1
    end
end
```

Let me know if you need more information in order to answer my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer to my problem.  If anyone wants to use the source, I am posting it below:

Queue module:

```
local q = {}
local q_mt = { __index = q }

function q.new()
    local nq = { first = 0, last = -1, list = {} }

    return setmetatable( nq, q_mt )
end

function q:pushLeft( value )
    local first = self.first - 1
    self.first = first
    self.list[first] = value
end

function q:pushRight( value )
    local last = self.last + 1
    self.last = last
    self.list[last] = value
end

function q:popLeft()
    local first = self.first
    if first > self.last then error( "list is empty" ) end
    local value = self.list[first]
    self.list[first] = nil
    self.first = first + 1
    return value
end

function q:popRight()
    local last = self.last
    if self.first > last then error( "list is empty" ) end
    local value = self.list[last]
    self.list[last] = nil
    self.last = last - 1
    return value
end

return q
```

The following module creates a vector field which points towards a goal when pathFind.findPath is called:

```
local q = require( "Queue" )

local pathFind = {}
local pathFind_mt = { __index = pathFind }

--  Private Functions

local function genDistMap( g, rtx, rty )      -<-<-<- genDistMap is the brushfire part
    local q = q.new()
    local g = g
    g[rtx][rty].v = true
    g[rtx][rty].dist = 0
    local s = {}
    s[1] = rtx
    s[2] = rty
    s[3] = g[rtx][rty][1]
    s.dist = 0
    q:pushRight( s )
    s = nil

    while( q.list[q.first] ~= nil ) do
        local n = q:popLeft()
        for i = 1, #n[3] do
            local x, y = n[3][i][1], n[3][i][2]
            if( g[x][y].v ~= true ) then
                g[x][y].v = true
                local t = {}
                t[1] = x
                t[2] = y
                t[3] = g[x][y][1]
                t.dist = n.dist + 1
                g[x][y].dist = n.dist + 1
                q:pushRight( t )
                t = nil
            end
        end
    end

    return g
end

local function genVectorField( nodes )
    local nodes = nodes

    for i = 2, #nodes - 1 do
        for j = 2, #nodes[i] - 1 do
            local a = nodes[i - 1][j].dist - nodes[i + 1][j].dist
            local b = nodes[i][j - 1].dist - nodes[i][j + 1].dist
            local c = math.sqrt( a*a + b*b )
            nodes[i][j].vX = a/c*5
            nodes[i][j].vY = b/c*5
        end
    end

    return nodes
end

--  Public Functions

function pathFind.new()
    local newPathFind = {}

    return setmetatable ( newPathFind, pathFind_mt )
end

function pathFind.findPath( nodeSet, rootX, rootY )
    local nodes = nodeSet

    nodes = genDistMap( nodes, rootX, rootY )

    nodes = genVectorField( nodes )

    return( nodes )
end

return pathFind
```